# Change duration of currently playing clip

Tags: exoplayer2.x

I need to change the duration of the currently playing clip in order to insert other clips.

I need to be able to update the playlist on the fly. This involves changing the currently playing clip duration, inserting some other clips (these are ads), and finally inserting a new clip which is the remaining section of the first currently playing clip. That last clip will have the start be the location of where we were last at.

I am using ClippingMediaSource objects and adding them to a ContactenatingMediaSource collection.

```
ConcatenatingMediaSource mediaSource;
private ConcatenatingMediaSource buildMediaSources(final ClipData[] clipList)
{
    ArrayList<MediaSource> sources = new ArrayList<MediaSource>();

    DataSource.Factory manifestDataSourceFactory =
            new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("ua");
    DashChunkSource.Factory dashChunkSourceFactory =
            new DefaultDashChunkSource.Factory(
                    new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("ua", BANDWIDTH_METER));

    for (ClipData clip : clipList)
    {
        String url = clip.getDashManifestURL();
        if (url == null)
        {
            url = clip.getHlsManifestURL();
        }
        MediaSource ms = new DashMediaSource.Factory(dashChunkSourceFactory,
                manifestDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(url));
        ClippingMediaSource cms = new ClippingMediaSource(ms, clip.getStartOffset(), clip.getStopOffset());
        sources.add(cms);
    }

    ConcatenatingMediaSource cms = new ConcatenatingMediaSource();
    cms.addMediaSources(sources);
    return cms;
}
mediaSource = buildMediaSources(clipList);
m_player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
```

The code above works on the initial run but I do not know how to set the first clip to a different duration while that same clip is playing. The first clip has not yet reached the duration that I need to change it to.